# Oracle Update with Subselect with Multiple Joins

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a script that includes an Oracle query to update the scheduled finish date of a project to the revised end date that was submitted through a change request, but the date is not being updated upon running the script.

I'm unsure whether this is a problem with my query or something else. Before I delve any deeper, does this query look like it should work? (I'm currently unable to test the query against the database itself.)

```
UPDATE Project pr
SET pr.ScheduledFinish = (SELECT ch.RevisedEndDate
                          FROM Change ch
                          JOIN ChangeRequests cr ON cr.ID = ch.ID
                          JOIN RisksAndIssues ri ON ri.ID = cr.ID
                          JOIN Project pr ON pr.ID = ri.PK_ID
                          WHERE pr.ID = ?)
WHERE pr.ID = (SELECT ID
               FROM Change ch
               WHERE ch.ID = ?)
```

Note: The ? in the query is a bind variable that will take on the value of the record currently being worked on. ie. If the Change Request being operated on has an ID of 1214, the ? will be 1214 once the script runs.

Thanks in advance.

Update:

I believe this is the correct logic:

```
UPDATE Project pr
SET pr.ScheduledFinish = (SELECT ch.RevisedEndDate
                          FROM Change ch
                          JOIN ChangeRequests cr ON cr.ID = ch.ID
                          JOIN RisksAndIssues ri ON ri.ID = cr.ID
                          JOIN Project pr ON pr.ID = ri.PK_ID
                          WHERE pr.ID = ?)
WHERE pr.ID = (SELECT ID
               FROM RisksAndIssues ri
               JOIN ChangeRequests cr ON cr.ID = ri.ID
               JOIN Change ch ON ch.ID = cr.ID
               JOIN Project pr ON pr.ID = ri.PK_ID
               WHERE pr.ID = ?)
```

Gordon, you were correct. I was trying to match a Change ID with a Project ID, but they don't correlate. So this new subselect in the WHERE clause of the update should fix the linkage issue.

Comment: I suspect that you are very confused on the layout of the tables.  Sample data would really help.  It is highly unlikely that all those tables are connected on the same `id` column.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added an update. I believe this was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no `change.id` that matches your project id.  It is very suspicious that all the `JOIN` columns are called `ID`.  I would expect something more like this:

Wouldn't this express the logic you want?

```
UPDATE Project pr
SET pr.ScheduledFinish = (SELECT ch.RevisedEndDate
                          FROM Change ch JOIN
                               ChangeRequests cr
                               ON cr.ID = ch.ChangeID JOIN
                               RisksAndIssues ri
                               ON ri.ID = cr.RiskID
                          WHERE ri.ProjectID = pr.ID
                         )
WHERE pr.ID = (SELECT ch.projectID
               FROM Change ch
               WHERE ch.ID = ?
              )
```

However, I don't know the actual names of the columns in your table, so this is just a guess.

Note that this removes the `Project` reference in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Project pr
SET pr.ScheduledFinish = (SELECT ch.RevisedEndDate
                          FROM Change ch
                          JOIN ChangeRequests cr ON cr.ID = ch.ID
                          JOIN RisksAndIssues ri ON ri.ID = cr.ID
                          JOIN Project pr ON pr.ID = ri.PK_ID
                          WHERE pr.ID = ?)
WHERE pr.ID = (SELECT ID
               FROM RisksAndIssues ri
               JOIN ChangeRequests cr ON cr.ID = ri.ID
               JOIN Change ch ON ch.ID = cr.ID
               JOIN Project pr ON pr.ID = ri.PK_ID
               WHERE pr.ID = ?);
```

There are a few issues with your query - for a start, you haven't aliased the ID column in the second subquery - which ID are you after? pr, ch, ri, ... ?
Also, you've got an unnecessary join to `project` in your subqueries; you could correlate that to the table you're updating, since it's the same table.

You could rewrite this to something like:

```
UPDATE Project pr
SET pr.ScheduledFinish = (SELECT ch.RevisedEndDate
                          FROM Change ch
                          INNER JOIN ChangeRequests cr ON cr.ID = ch.ID
                          INNER JOIN RisksAndIssues ri ON ri.ID = cr.ID
                          WHERE ri.PK_ID = pr.ID)
WHERE pr.ID = ?
AND   EXISTS (SELECT NULL
               FROM RisksAndIssues ri
               JOIN ChangeRequests cr ON cr.ID = ri.ID
               JOIN Change ch ON ch.ID = cr.ID
               WHERE ri.pk_id = pr.ID);
```

Or, even better, you could avoid repeating the subquery by using a `MERGE` statement, e.g.:

```
MERGE INTO project tgt
  USING (SELECT ri.pk_id,
                ch.revisedenddate
         FROM   CHANGE ch
         INNER JOIN ChangeRequests cr ON cr.ID = ch.ID
         INNER JOIN RisksAndIssues ri ON ri.ID = cr.ID
         WHERE  ri.pk_id = ?) src
    ON (tgt.id = src.pk_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET tgt.scheduledfinish = src.revisedenddate;
```

Comment: In regards to you assigning the ? to ri.pk_id in the MERGE... The ? will only take on the value of the Change ID the script is running for. So the only fields that can appropriately take on the ? are (Change) ch.ID and (RisksAndIssues) ri.ID. The only link on ri.PK_ID is (Project) pr.ID.

Comment: I put that there because I’m your update statement, you have `pr.id = ?` and also `pr.id = ri.pk_id` in the join condition. So I have moved the bind variable(I hope you’re using bind variables?) straight to the ri.pk_id. If that’s not correct, there’s something wrong with your existing update statement.

Comment: Yes, that was the error I noticed while talking to Gordon. That bind variable can only be the "objectInstanceID", and in my case, the objectInstanceID will only take on the value of the current (Change) ch.ID the script is running on - which is related to, thus could also be used for, (RisksAndIssues) ri.ID.

Comment: I leave it up to you to amend the above statements for your specific case. I’ve given you some ideas. If you can’t test your statement, I recommend you create a test case in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk) - which you can then share with other people!